# Spark check if any words from array of dataframe is contained in another list?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have read a json file and converted to dataframe in spark.It has a column skills that contains the list of values. Now I want to filter the dataframe such that the column skills has any value of another list.

For example:

```
skill= ["A", "B", "C", "D"] and list=["A", "Z"]
skill= ["E", "B", "C", "D"] and list=["A", "Z"]
```

Then the filter code should show the first row and ignore the other row. I am trying it in scala.

Comment: Is `list` also a column in your dataframe or do you just have one single list to be used for all rows in the dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not having 2.4, you need to use udf(). Check this out:

```
val df = Seq(Array("A", "B", "C", "D"), Array("E", "B", "C", "D")).toDF("skills")
def skill_check(x:Seq[String]):Boolean = {
  val b = x.map( p=> Seq("A", "Z").exists( y => y==p)).filter(x=>x)
  if ( b.isEmpty ) false else true
}
val udf_skill_check = udf( skill_check(_:Seq[String]))
df.withColumn("check",udf_skill_check('skills) ).filter("check").show(false)
```

Results:

```
+------------+-----+
|skills      |check|
+------------+-----+
|[A, B, C, D]|true |
+------------+-----+
```

If you don't want to use UDF, then you can introduce a new column for the check list i.e ["A","Z"}, explode.. then check if the skills contains the exploded items, filter and then drop duplicates on the skills column. Roundabout, but works

```
val df = Seq(Array("A", "B", "C", "D"), Array("E", "B", "C", "D")).toDF("skills")
val df2 = df.withColumn("chk1",lit(Array("A","Z"))) // New column
df2.withColumn("chk2",explode('chk1)).withColumn("chk3", array_contains('skills,'chk2)).filter("chk3").select("skills").dropDuplicates().show(false)

+------------+
|skills      |
+------------+
|[A, B, C, D]|
+------------+
```